# Combining year, month and day to create date in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which has select dropdowns for year, month and day.

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.mergeDate('day', event.target.value)}>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  ...
</select>

<select onChange={(event) => this.mergeDate('month', event.target.value)}>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  ...
</select>

<select onChange={(event) => this.mergeDate('year', event.target.value)}>
  <option value="1977">1e977</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I need to create date out of these values and store them in the `birthday` field of state. In order to do that, I created three additional properties as `date_day`, `date_mth` and `date_year`.

```
this.state =    {
                        name: '',
                        email: '',
                        birthday: '',
                        country: '',
                        date_day: '',
                        date_mth: '',
                        date_year: ''
                 }
```

And on the select dropdown change, I created a function that merges the values using `Date()` function as follows:

```
mergeDate(type, value)
{

        if (type === 'year')  { this.setState({ date_year: value }) }
        if (type === 'month') { this.setState({ date_mth: value  }) }
        if (type === 'day')   { this.setState({ date_day: value  }) }

        console.log('merging date now '); // --> Works!

        let newDate = new Date(this.state.date_year, this.state.date_mth, this.state.date_day);

        console.log(newDate);             // --> successful, but shows date value of last onChange event

        this.setState({ birthday: newDate });

        console.log(this.state);          // --> {...., birthday: '', ....}

}
```

In this function, the second console.log shows the date set on last onChange event. The last console.log logs empty value in the `birthday`. I'm guessing the problem is because of `asynchronous behavior` of `setState` which I do not yet understand. Can anyone please explain to me the reason behind and solution to the problem?

==========

## UPDATE

According to Asad, `setState` is `asynchronous` and any action to be done after setting the state is complete should be passed as a parameter to the setState function. I tried:

```
postUpdate()
{
        let newDate = new Date(this.state.date_year, this.state.date_mth, this.state.date_day);
        this.setState({ birthday : newDate });
}

mergeDate(type, value)
{ 
        if (type === 'year')  { this.setState({ date_year:value  }, this.postUpdate(newDate))}
        if (type === 'month') { this.setState({ date_mth: value  }, this.postUpdate(newDate))}
        if (type === 'day')   { this.setState({ date_day: value  }, this.postUpdate(newDate))}     
 }
```

This is still giving me the same output - shows date value of last onChange event. What am I missing?

========

## SOLUTION

The solution is to not pass the function alone but as a function.

```
mergeDate(type, value)
{ 
        if (type === 'year')  { this.setState({ date_year:value  }, () => this.postUpdate())}
        if (type === 'month') { this.setState({ date_mth: value  }, () => this.postUpdate())}
        if (type === 'day')   { this.setState({ date_day: value  }, () => this.postUpdate())}     
 }
```

Comment: You have to remember that `setState` is asynchronous. If you want to do stuff after it, you should pass a callback as a second argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Asad. What kind of callback should I send?

Comment: Your problem from the update is that you aren't actually passing the function, you're invoking it. You just need to pass it the same way I have in my code, i.e. `this.setState({ date_day: value  }, postUpdate)`. In your case you've set it up as a method, so you would need `, this.postUpdate.bind(this))`, but at that point what you're already doing is probably more readable.

Comment: That's good info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, as React often batches state updates for performance. This means you can't rely on fresh state being available in statements following `setState`. If you rely on ordering of changes, you should pass a callback, like so:

```
mergeDate(type, value)
{
        function postUpdate() {
            // All of the code from after your if statements
        }
        if (type === 'year')  { this.setState({ date_year: value }, postUpdate) }
        if (type === 'month') { this.setState({ date_mth: value  }, postUpdate) }
        if (type === 'day')   { this.setState({ date_day: value  }, postUpdate) }

}
```

In general though, you should simply be doing all your computations up front and just calling `setState` once at the end of the function with all your desired changes to the state.

Comment: Take a minute to look at my question, please?

Comment: I figured it out. The information was very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @anonym Sorry, was offline at the time, but glad you figured it out.